# Cannot push (Missing delta base)

Tags: git, scmmanager

We have our internal git repos managed with scm-manager. About 3 weeks ago we moved offices and the server became offline until last friday. Now I cannot push my local changes back to the server.

The first thing I had to do was change the config file and update the "origin" url to the new IP. But now the problem is as follows:

```
Counting objects: 416, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (333/333), done.
Writing objects: 100% (343/343), 330.09 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 343 (delta 252), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: unpack failed: error Missing delta base 00f3fe0c3202aeff6be55b8733ddf61c80feaf4a
To http://█████████████████████████
! [remote rejected] master -> master (n/a (unpacker error))
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://█████████████████████████'
```

I can't find the ID "00f3fe0c3202aeff6be55b8733ddf61c80feaf4a" anywhere in my history.

I'm on Windows 7. Installed tools: TortoiseGit, SourceTree and GitBash/GitGui.

Comment: Do you see any stack traces in the server logs?

Comment: Stacktraces, no but I've found out that our server somehow can access the history but not the sources. It shows a 500 error and there's a Warning in the log: "sonia.scm.web.filter.BasicAuthenticationFilter - username or password is null/empty"

Comment: Have you checked the path in the repository configuration of SCM-Manager?

Comment: Yes. It's correct. I just found out that aall our other repos on the server work fine.

Comment: Check the repository using `git fsck`

Comment: Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (602/602), done.
dangling blob 10725e49ea7ab0df056c078fc7acf73cb7007940
dangling blob 80928075a71b15533d1e6ada69d317aa5808028d
dangling commit cd66e3067d5f9e598003a56a65f976fe11b590ba
dangling blob 00795e713e7173db1e026fb17185761dc74a886a
dangling blob 818cd97bf1e145676484e375658ba3b89116e74f

Comment: Can you checkout and push to this repository from another machine? It sounds like a local repository problem.